# Get Username from Get-WinEvent

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to find a user who uninstalled a program on the Server. Here's the script I am using and the result. From Event Viewer, I am able to see the User but looks like the Get-WinEvent returns UserId but no Username. Is there a way to return Username for event 1034 from Get-WinEvent?

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Application'; Id=1034} -MaxEvents 1 | format-list
```

---

```
TimeCreated  : 6/17/2013 1:41:27 PM
ProviderName : MsiInstaller
Id           : 1034
Message      : Windows Installer removed the product. Product Name: PAL. Product Version: 2.3.2. Product Language:
           1033. Manufacturer: PAL. Removal success or error status: 0.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using .NET's [SecurityIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.aspx), [as described here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730940.aspx).

```
Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1000 | foreach {
  $sid = $_.userid;
  if($sid -eq $null) { return; }
  $objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid);
  $objUser = $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]);
  Write-Host $objUser.Value;
}
```

For non-null user IDs, I was able to successfully identify user names.